# Not able to get attachments from Twitter message (DM) in Spring Integration

Tags: spring-integration, spring-tool-suite, twitter-streaming-api

I am using Spring Integration 2.2.4 to stream Twitter messages. I am able to get the text messages but not finding the attachments. I'm using below adapter to get messages from Twitter:

```
int-twitter:dm-inbound-channel-adapter
```

Comment: That is so old version. Try to upgrade and come back to us with news

Comment: using 4.3.6.RELEASE now. still not able to get the attachment url. can see only sender, recipient objects.

Comment: Doesn't `extraData` of the `DirectMessage` contain that for you?

Comment: Yes it contains the necessary details as map object. Thank you. :)